# Haskell comparing two chars

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

```
compLetters :: Char -> Char -> Char
compLetters a b = chr (min (ord a ord b))
```

I am trying to compare to characters to see which one appears first in the alphabet. I tried to do this using the above code but an error appears. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: While we can see what the error is, saying "an error appears" is the most uninformative statement you can include in a question. You should always include the error. Even if it is irrelevant to you, it might greatly help others to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 9):

Since `Char` implements `Ord`, you can just use `min` directly:

```
firstChar :: Char -> Char -> Char
firstChar a b = min a b
```

Or more simply

```
firstChar = min
```

Or you could just use `min` in your code

The reason why your code was failing is syntax.  You have

```
min (ord a ord b)
```

Which parses as

```
min (((ord a) ord) b)
```

Which says that `ord` takes 3 arguments and `min` takes 1 argument, but this doesn't type check.  Instead you should have

```
min (ord a) (ord b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Char is an instance of Ord, so you can just use (<).

```
> 'a' < 'b'
  True
```